# Where to find drivers for Epson W-3540

Tags: drivers, printing, epson

I can't seem to find drivers for Epson W-3540 All-in-One printer/scanner. Any ideas?

Comment: W vs WF? In case of WF - use those: https://www.epson.com/cgi-bin/Store/support/supDetail.jsp?oid=209704&infoType=Downloads&platform=OSF_O_LINUX

Answer (score 1):

Type your model into here http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/searchModuleFromResult

and get a list of options

my favorite is the [epson printer utility](https://download3.ebz.epson.net/dsc/f/03/00/04/54/29/d4b1abe3ca145bf733274a098c8455d79eec5705/epson-printer-utility_1.0.0-1lsb3.2_amd64.deb).